# Images not displaying in GridView from SQL database when debugging yet display when I test query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a webform with a girdview that shows food name and food picture.
[image: here is the test query output, as you can see the images are shown]

However when I run my programme in Google Chrome I get this grid-view.
[image: No images displayed in grid-view.]

The images are not displayed in the GridView from SQL database when debugging yet display when I test query?

Comment: While running in Chrome see what source image url is coming .

Comment: http://localhost:52670/System.Byte[]

does this mean i need to store the image within a folder in the project in order for them to be referenced correctly?

Comment: Share your code snippet and also image url is stored in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data URIs to display the images without having to store them. See here: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Do keep in mind however that this means you will be streaming the data in the http response for the page on every request. You get no benefit of browser or server caching.

Consider using cloud (or hosted) storage and CDN rather than storing the file data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is store the images in the database using by converting them to byte array and then retrieve them from database and display in gridview. The tutorial here can help you with it. [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/store-image-into-database-and-retrieve-in-a-gridview-display-using-c-sharp1)